# mpdf table width to fit A4 paper size

Tags: html, css, mpdf

I have been trying every possible solution to make table fill the width of the A4 paper. I am using mpdf to convert HTML to pdf. But table is never 100% width.
I tried giving width in 100%, 1000px, 180mm but none of them worked. Please Help.

I tried :

```
 <table width="1000px">   //style="width:100%;" or width:180mm or width:100px
 </table>
```

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

> It may help to you, customize page from mpdf configuration:

**Fullpage example:**

```
  include 'MPDF/mpdf.php';
  $pdf = new mPDF(); 
  $pdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
  $header ="Header html file or code";
  $footer ="Footer html file or code";
  $content ="Body html or code";

  $pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
  $pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
  $pdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

  $pdf->WriteHTML($content); // write the HTML into the PDF
  $pdf->Output("pdf/test.pdt", 'F'); // save to file because we can
```

**or you can use custom margin:**

```
  include 'MPDF/mpdf.php';
  $pdf = new mPDF(); 
  $pdf->ignore_invalid_utf8 = true;
  $header ="Header html file or code";
  $footer ="Footer html file or code";
  $content ="Body html or code";

  $pdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
  $pdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
  $pdf->AddPage('', // L - landscape, P - portrait 
    '', '', '', '',
    15, // margin_left
    15, // margin right
    30, // margin top
    30, // margin bottom
    10, // margin header
    10  // margin footer
  ); 

  $pdf->WriteHTML($content); // write the HTML into the PDF
  $pdf->Output("pdf/test.pdt", 'F'); // save to file because we can
```

Comment: The problem is in table width.

Comment: If your page's margin is default by set `15px` Then how it possible to make your table 100% width?

I think your layout are getting default margin that because  your table is not working as 100% width.

Comment: No. Paragraph written are covering 100% width. The only problem is in table width.